# PHP or MYSQL: bulk edit: result($_POST["keyword..and ID, into a new table, if not already exist, if yes skip and continue

Tags: php, mysql

(I have different problems i have to change, with PHP or MYSQL only.
I could not find a MYSQL solution, so iam working to get a php solution.)

**current structure:**

a product table, with many keyword columns i explode and update for each.
But I don`t want use these keyword1-keyword200 concept anymore. (So, the comma-list problem solved already with PHP.)

table PRODUCTS

```
 ID_PRODUCT   KEYWORDS_LIST       keyword1   keyword2  ...  keyword200
    1            red,blue,green
    2            red,blue,yellow
    ...          ...
    99000        black
```

**i want to have:**

```
table_PRODUCT_KEYWORDS
PRODUCT_ID    KEYWORD
1             red
1             blue
1             green
2             red
2             blue
99000         black
```

**current structure:**
I have an old backend php bulk script, that EXPLODE a comma list,replaces white spaces etc..
and updates the table PRODUCTS for each comma separated keyword, but i dont want this anymore.

table PRODUCTS **after** bulk edit:

```
 ID_PRODUCT   KEYWORDS_LIST       keyword1   keyword2  ...  keyword200
    1            red,blue,..green   red        blue    ...  green
    2            red,blue           red        blue 
    ...          ...                ...        ...     ...  ...
    99000        black              black
```

**current structure:** with PHP:
$exploded_Keyword = explode(",", $KEYWORDS_LIST);

```
<input type='text' name='keyword1".$res_id[$i]."' value='".$exploded_Keyword[1]."'>
..
<input type='text' name='keyword200".$res_id[$i]."' value='".$exploded_Keyword[200]."'>

... 
select id_parent from structure where id=".(int)$res_id[$i];
...
for($i=0;$i<count($res_id);$i++)

{
    $sql="update PRODUCTS set
    keyword1='".result($_POST["exploded_Keyword1".$res_id[$i]])."',
    *...*
    keyword200='".result($_POST["exploded_Keyword200".$res_id[$i]])."'
        where id_parent=".$res_id[$i];
        $db->execute($sql);
}
```

But it was a bad concept (noob)and the php code does not use the ID_PRODUCT.
I don`t know how to insert ID_PRODUCT and KEYWORD together. Because i have comma-lists, i use PHP explode, but i do not know, how to insert these exploded keywords into the new table_PRODUCT_KEYWORDS. Current php code does insert these into my old table PRODUCTS –

**i want to have:**

```
table_PRODUCT_KEYWORDS
PRODUCT_ID    KEYWORD
1             red
1             blue
1             green
2             red
2             blue
99000         black
```

**i created this new table already with:**

```
CREATE TABLE product_keywords (
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    keyword VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFEREFENCES products (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX (product_id, keyword)
);
```

Change PHP to insert
into my new table_PRODUCT_KEYWORDS
ID + KEYWORD
and check if ID+KEYWORD do already exist, if yes, skip it, but continue with next keyword, for each.

The number of KEYWORDS is from 1 up to 200. Therefore i have to take into account that the empty "exploded_KeywordXY(s)" should not be inserted.

= If a combination of PRODUCT_ID and KEYWORD exist, skip it **and continue** with next keyword.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: you need to have a loop (a foreach for instance) and on each iteration of the list of keyword you should insert it into the table you created keeping the same id of the product

Comment: @Nico Haase
Change my database from table PRODUCTS to table_PRODUCT_KEYWORDS. Because i have comma-lists, i use PHP explode, but i do not know, how to insert these exploded keywords into the new table_PRODUCT_KEYWORDS. Current php code does insert these into my old table PRODUCTS

Comment: @Lelio Faieta yes, this is what iam looking for, need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have the following string:

```
$string="red,blue,cyan,magenta";
```

that is the list of keywords for a product. This can be retrieved by a SELECT query on the db for a product id on the keywords_list field.
Assume also that you have a product id in a variable `$product_id` that again can be retrieved with the same query for the keyword list

Now let's create an array out of that string. Explode will create an array for us:

```
$string_arr=explode(',',$string);
```

Now let's insert the values in the keywords table. The foreach loop will take care of performing the same action for all the keywords whatever their number is:

```
foreach($string_arr as $keyword){
  $sql="INSERT INTO product_keywords SET 
        product_id=$product_id, keyword='$keyword'"
        $db->execute($sql);
}
```

Comment: If i use "insert ignore" to prevent duplicate, will it skip the complete query or only the exact one $product_ID $keyword ? 
You mean:  
$exploded_Keyword = $rs->row["keywords_list"];
foreach($exploded_Keyword_arr as $keyword){
  $sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO product_keywords SET 
        product_id=$res_id[$i], keyword=$keyword"
        $db->execute($sql);

Comment: Yes, that's true. OP is using a form to pass the exploded keywords. What I want to explain him is that it is not strictly necessary. But yes, my answer with your comment works fine!

Comment: @WIll B. thank you, i will try to combine Lelio and your answer for a "try and error" :) Also have to try "insert ignore", or a a where. Any ideas?

Comment: @babawo it will perform a specific query for each keyword. So it will skip only the exact combination of product_id and keyword

Comment: @babawo technically you could use `INSERT IGNORE INTO product_keywords SET product_id=$product_id, keyword='$keyword'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE keyword=VALUES(keyword);` if you are wanting to insert or update the keyword value if it already exists. See: [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: @Lelio Faieta , you mean with a simple "insert ignore": That would be great. Big thanks guys. Trying to solve this days already.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment, if `$res_id[$i]` is the product id, it would be `name='keyword[".$res_id[$i]."][]'` and `foreach ($_POST['keyword'][$product_id] as $keyword)`